# Extracting and Assigning Data to Variable - MSSQL via PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have connected to an MS-SQL Server 2008 database via PHP and now I want to extract data to variables, how is that done?

I have the following code:

```
$myServer = "214187-1";
$myUser = "ytuser";
$myPass = "***********";
$myDB = "*********"; 

//create an instance of the  ADO connection object
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")
  or die("Cannot start ADO");

//define connection string, specify database driver
$connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=".$myServer.";UID=".$myUser.";PWD=".$myPass.";DATABASE=".$myDB; 
  $conn->open($connStr); //Open the connection to the database

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT FacebookAppID, FacebookAppSecret, TwitterConsumerKey, TwitterConsumerSecret, LinkedinAPIKey, LinkedinSecretKey FROM Systems WHERE SystemID = " $G_SYSTEMID;

$FacebookAppID = ;
$FacebookAppSecret = ;    
$TwitterConsumerKey = ;
$TwitterConsumerSecret = ;
$LinkedinAPIKey = ;
$LinkedinSecretKey = ;

$rs->Close();
$conn->Close();

$rs = null;
$conn = null;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

neojakey

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into a few things - somebody telling you exactly how to do it isn't going to help you.

First up, learn how to structure your query properly with some basic SQL knowledge [Basic SQL Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp)

Next, look at how php executes a SQL statement - the two main commands you'll need to define a variable are:

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) - this is used to execute the query.

and

[mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) - this is for getting the data into an array from the mysql_query (note: you dont have to use '...fetch_array' - there are others such as '...fetch_row'.

Read up on those and you'll have the knowledge to do what you want.